# Add a slideshow to Tictail

Tags: slideshow

I basically just want to add a slideshow to a current shop. I've never used Tictail before and it was great and very easy to set up (I set it up just so I could learn how it works).

But I can't get my head around this because I can't even get to this menu:
http://help.tictail.com/customer/portal/articles/1206116-change-your-store-s-landing-page

Anyone who can help me into right direction?

This is how it looks like when I enter the settings-screen:

[image]

Comment: [https://tictail.com/docs/templates](Documentation): `{{#slideshow-<size>}}`eg. `{{#slideshow-500}}{{/slideshow-500}}`.. to get all images `{{#all_images}}<img src="{{url-500}}" alt="{{title}}">{{/all_images}}`

Answer (score 0):

you have to open your dashboard in the top right side then click the arrows if you need HTML otherwise you can change the templates.

good luck

Comment: Instead of posting a new answer, you should just fix (edit) your existing one.